# iad banner is displayed in simulator and device but not in app store

Tags: ios, iad

I added iAd to my app. All works fine if i test it on simulator and device.
The app is also not rejected and the review is also successful.

But if I download my app from the app store and open it.
I cant find any iAd banner!

I set up the iAd contract.

Can someone help me or had already the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not available advertise for certain time, for your country.

*iAd campaigns currently run in Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Mexico, New Zealand, Russia, Spain, Switzerland, Taiwan, the United Kingdom and the United States

Comment: Ok, I'm in Germany so it should work. Is there anything what I can check?

Comment: I don't know, maybe advertisers have other targets to show or not banner for certain user. How long are you testing your app from AppStore?